# Regex to find string containing special characters in text

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to formulate a regular expression that will allow me to find a string within a piece of text, if the string exists on its own i.e. not within another word (but surrounded by special characters is ok).

```
/\bword\b/i
```

The above regex works fine, and finds "word" in the text. The problem comes when the word I want to find is something like "c++". In this case it matches on any occurrence of the "c" character on it's own. I've tried escaping the "+" characters but it doesn't make any difference. I'm assuming because "+" is a non-word character, I'm possibly going down the wrong route and using word boundaries is not what I should be doing.

So I guess the question is, how can I use a regular expression to find a string in a piece of text, on it's own, and regardless of whether the string is alphanumeric or contains special characters. So in the following piece of text it should match on the 3 occurences of "c++":

```
c++
(c++)
perl/c++/assembly
```

But it should not match on the following:

```
maniac++
c++abc
```

This is intended so that my script can tell if a specific skill exists within a user's CV/resume. I'm using this with PHP's preg_match_all() function.

I've done a lot of searching but can't come up with a solution, hopefully someone with good regex knowledge can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(?<!\w)(c\+\+)(?!\w)/
```

The `(?<!\w)` is a negative lookbehind clause, meaning that a word character should not immediately precede your pattern.  The `(?!\w)` part is negative lookahead, meaning that a word character should not immediately follow.

Hope this helps!

Comment: [:-p](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df91dec2fa93f691b683af93bb6973a64d8cf38e)

Comment: Btw, if you're new to developing regexs, you might be interested to know that they can be tested quickly in command line perl.  The following linux command shows which of your example strings are matched: `echo -e 'c++\n(c++)\nperl/c++/assembly\nmaniac++\nc++abc' | perl -lane '/^(.*(?<!\w)(c\+\+)(?!\w).*)$/ && print $1'`  Just don't try reading it out loud without taking a deep breath ;-)